# Google Maps mobile: can't touch and drag to move map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, fullpage.js

I have a embebbed google map in my website, everything works right except one thing:
On mobile devices I am not being able to drag and move the map (touch, hold and move). Instead of moving the map, it scrolls my website wrongly.

I also have to say I am using [fullPage plugin](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) and the map is at the last section.

Above is some JS code:

```
function initializeMap() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.632587,-58.789862);
  var mapProp = {
    center:myLatlng,
    zoom:15,
    scrollwheel: true,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title:"Somma"
    });
}

$(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    paddingTop: '70px',
    paddingBottom: padBot,
    scrollOverflow: true,
    normalScrollElements: '#googleMap',
    anchors:['home', 'estudio', 'servicios', 'portfolio', 'show-portfolio', 'clientes', 'contacto'],
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
      if(index == 4 && nextIndex == 5 && shouldSkip){
        $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(6);
        return false;
      }

      else if(index == 6 && nextIndex == 5 && shouldSkip){
        $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(4);
        return false;
      }
    },
    afterRender: function () {
      initializeMap();
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, too. I thought there would be something like an option to disable fullpage.js getting the touch events on the maps, but I can not find it. I ended up using another popup windows(dialog), which contains the maps to solve the problem. So the end product [looks like this](http://ubutton.github.io/).

Also look at [the code here](https://github.com/ubutton/ubutton.github.io/blob/master/index.html#L53).

Comment: Your web ended very nice. What I did is add a transparent invisible div that overlays the map, which does only overlays in mobilephones (because in desktop the map works fine), so this way I prevent the web from scrolling unwantedly to other sections when the user tries to use the map. But on the other hand, this way users can't interact with the map in mobile phones

Answer (score 0):

It seems [to be a bug](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1281) related with the use of the maps iframe.

I would recommend you to force the open of the map in another tab whenever the user clicks on it. Cover it with an overlay or use instead a map image.

In a normal case, you could deal with it by using the `normalScrollElements` option.